# Suppose that group $G$ has a presentation $\langle a,b\mid a^{4} = b^{7} = 1, ab=ba^{3}\rangle$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Suppose that group $G$ has a presentation  $\langle a,b \mid a^{4}= b^{7}=1, ab=ba^{3}\rangle$. Show that the order of $G$ is  $28$.

I can only try combining and permuting $a$ and $b$ and eliminating them by the presentation of $G$ to get the answer. It's tough work. I think there must be some easy and 'systematic' metheds to solve the question. Any ideas?

Comment: For the sake of saying it, it might "seem" as though there is a systematic way to solve the problem, but in general there isn't (although in your particular case, of course there is). Being able to take a presentation and figure everything out is actually extremely difficult (and sometimes not possible). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_problem_for_groups

Comment: @DerekHolt  There is no nontrivial action of $C_7$ on $C_4$.

Comment: @ChrisCuster You are correct of course! I made the mistake of assuming that the result to be proved is right. It is wrong: the order of $G$ is $14$, not $28$, and the element $a^2$ is trivial. (I downvoted as an irritable reaction!)

Comment: @DerekHolt An easy mistake to make on this site.  Thanks for catching it.

Answer (score 2):

Let us show that the order of $G$ is $\color{red}{14}$,
and that it is commutative.

From $ab=ba^3$ we get $aba=ba^3\ a=ba^4=b$. This then gives $a^2ba^2= a(aba)a=aba=b$.
Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
1 &= b^7\\
&=(aba)^7\\
&=aba\ aba\ aba\ aba\ aba\ aba\ aba\\
&=ab\ a^2ba^2\ b \ a^2ba^2\ b\ a^2ba^2\ ba\\
&=ab\ b\ b\ b\ b\ b\ ba\\
&=ab^7a\\
&=aa\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(I hope i typed it correctly, each line containing the many $b$'s should have seven of them in the corresponding non-commutative product.)
So we in fact have $a^2=1$.

*Now we are following [user1729](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/10513/user1729)...*

So $ab=ba^3=ba\ a^2=ba$, and $G$ is commutative.
There is only one such structure, $G\cong\Bbb Z/2\times\Bbb Z/7\cong\Bbb Z/14$.

---

*Computer check added...* Well, i was also curious to see the opinion of [sage](https://www.sagemath.org) on the above...

```
sage: F.<a,b> = FreeGroup()
sage: G = F / [a^4, b^7, a*b*a*b^-1]
sage: G.is_finite()
True
sage: G.order()
14
sage: G.is_commutative()
True
```

Next time i will try this first...

Comment: Your description of the group via permutations is perhaps more complicated than required: as $a^2=1$, the relation $ab=ba^3$ is equivalent to $ab=ba$, so the group is simply $\mathbb{Z_2\times Z_7}$.

Comment: @user1729 Oh, yes, the group is commutative, the above stuff was typed earlier... After some edits of the OP i have to adjust, and correct the error, thanks!